# Auth0: Limiting access based on scopes

Tags: c#, auth0

I'm in the process of setting up authorization for a Web API.
The API will both be receiving post/put requests from a m2m application, and get/post/put requests from a front-end application.

I understand that I can use scopes to limit the access that these applications receive, but I have no idea how to implement it.

I've made the scopes I require, but how do I actually check the scopes, and then grant access to GET/POST etc based on that?

If this is a stupid question, I apologize. I've only been programming for a year.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about or look into Role-based authorization (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1) - Note that URL to the Microsoft Docs are for DotNet Core version 3.1

If configured correctly, you can use annotation on top of your methods that you want to specify a scope:

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
}
```

or

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, PowerUser")]
public class ControlPanelController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SetTime()
    {
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult ShutDown()
    {
    }
}
```

Then you could create a Role for your M2M application and allow this application only specific methods and the users that use your frontend can have other roles. As you can see in the second example, you can set Authoriziation Roles on the Controller itself and then later on your methods bring the scope down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll take a look into it!